# Algorithm for (binary) integer programming

Tags: integer-programming

I am looking for an algorithm that can solve the following (binary) integer programming problem. The problem description is given below:
\begin{align*}
&\max\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{j\in J}g_{ij}w_{ij} \\
&\forall i \in I, \sum_{j\in J}g_{ij}\leqslant 1 \\
& \forall j \in J, \sum_{i\in I}g_{ij}\leqslant 2 \\
& \forall j \in J,\sum_{i\in I}g_{ij}w_{ij}\leqslant x_j,
\end{align*}
 where $\forall i\in I, j\in J,g_{ij}\in\{0,1\}; w_{ij}\in \mathbb{R_+};x_j\in\mathbb{R_+}.$ $g_{ij}$ is decision variable, $w_{ij}$s and $x_{ij}$s are given such that $\forall j \in J, w_{ij}\leqslant x_j.$ Index sets $I$ and $J$ are finite.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a practical problem (i.e. you actually want an answer to specific instances) rather than a theoretical one, you should probably look first to software such as Cplex rather than implementing an algorithm yourself.

I might note that the constraints
$\sum_{j} g_{ij} \le 1$ mean that $\{g_{ij}: j \in J\}$ is in Cplex terminology a "SOS Type 1", and Cplex can take advantage of that to 
improve efficiency.

Comment: this is not a practical problem. I only need the existence of an algorithm that can solve this. I do not need actual solutions.

Comment: Then any of the usual algorithms for binary integer programming will do.  Or even brute force.